# Where to store static files from a PaaS?

Tags: heroku, routes, openshift, assets, static-files

I am looking at using either OpenShift or Heroku for my Bottle-built API and HTML+JavaScript+CSS frontends.

Deploying my custom API is straightforward, and I can trivially route my static files through the API.

There are many advantages to serving static files through a web-server (nginx, apache etc.) instead.

How do I do this on OpenShift or heroku?

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenShift

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^application/media/(.+)$ /static/media/$1 [L]
```

> Then copy the media/* content to yourapp/wsgi/static/media/ and it should just work.
>
> Note: The ^application/ part of the URI match is required.

**Reference**: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/bottle-openshift-quickstart